# Toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Greetings everyone!
I want to know if its possible to find out if a div with id="contentEditDiv" excist AFTER the link i just clicked.
My goal is to toggle (remove) only the ajax thats been loaded and inserted after the link.

```
<a href="#" class="contentEditLink" id="1">link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="contentEditLink" id="2">link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="contentEditLink" id="3">link 3</a>
```

```
$('a.contentEditLink').click(function(){
if( $('#contentEditDiv').length ) {
    $('#contentEditDiv').remove();
}
else {
    var strContentID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + strContentID).after('<div id="contentEditDiv"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>');
    $('#contentEditDiv').load('test.php?contentID=' + strContentID);
}
});
```

Comment: Something like If this.after($('#contentEditDiv').length but with the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$('a.contentEditLink').click(function(){
    if ($(this).next('#contentEditDiv').length) {
        $(this).next('#contentEditDiv').remove();
    } else {
        [...]
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very simple, thanks. Cant believe I couldn't figure this out my self. Guess Im still very novice.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Give a corresponding ID to each one, since you're IDs must be unique anyway (which they are not currently, if all 3 links are clicked)

```
$('a.contentEditLink').click(function(){    
    var strContentID = $(this).attr('id');
    if( $('#contentEditDiv' + strContentID).length ) {
        $('#contentEditDiv' + strContentID).remove();
    }    
    $('#' + strContentID).after('<div id="contentEditDiv'+strContentID+'"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>');
    $('#contentEditDiv' + strContentID).load('test.php?contentID=' + strContentID);
});
```

### **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuMg7/)**